# len() of datetime.datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, string-length

I am trying to get the length of various types of data in python:

```
 if type(rowoutClipFC[fieldnum]) in (int, float, datetime.datetime):
       lenrowoutClipFC = len(str(rowoutClipFC[fieldnum]))
 else:
       lenrowoutClipFC = len(rowoutClipFC[fieldnum])
```

The types I have come across so far are int(), float(), str(), str() with ascii characters, datetime.datetime.

I need to convert the int(), float(), datetime.datetime objects to str() so I can get length, whereas I do not need to do this with the str() and str() with ascii. For some reason, datetime.datetime does not pass the smell test of the first if statement, so it errors. I'm not sure why it isn't....

the error returns:

```
lenrowoutClipFC = len(rowoutClipFC[fieldnum])
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()
```

So, it's moving onto the else statement which is not what I was expecting...

**EDIT:**

What I am expecting is this:

```
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("Strategic_Land_Resource_Planning_Area"):
    type(row.APPROVAL_DATE)
```

This returns `datetime.datetime`

The field in the table I am pulling the data from is a 'date' field. So, I guess it returns a datetime.datetime type...even though someone mentioned that there is no such thing as a datetime.datetime type?

So, I further test:

```
import datetime
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("Strategic_Land_Resource_Planning_Area"):
    if type(row.APPROVAL_DATE) == datetime.datetime:
         print 'Yes"
```

This returns `Yes`

So, I am not sure why my script at the top doesn't satisfy the if condition....

I tries using `isinstance` with the same reults. It doesn't satisfy in the if statement.

Comment: Do `len(str(datetime.datetime...))`. You cannot get the length of a `class` object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the length of an object? Should the length of `[1]` be 1, its length as a list, or 3, its length if you convert it to a string first?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the type of datetime.datetime isn't 'datetime', it's 'type'. That's because datetime.datetime is the class, not an instance of the class.

E.g.

```
>>> import datetime

>>> type(datetime.datetime)
<type 'type'>

>>> type(datetime.datetime.now())
<type 'datetime.datetime'>

>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>>
```

The docs recommend if you're testing the type of something, to use isinstance() rather than type() (ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

Try this instead:

```
field = rowoutClipFC[fieldnum]
if type(field) in (int, float) or isinstance(field, datetime.datetime):
    lenrowoutClipFC = len(str(field))
else:
    lenrowoutClipFC = len(field)
```

Even simpler, you could just do this:

```
field = rowoutClipFC[fieldnum]
lenrowoutClipFC = len(str(field))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I tried your method and I still can't get the if statement to satisfy. See my edited portion of my post. Thanks, Mike

Comment: I've added a new answer below to ask questions, ill delete it once we get tot he bottom of the issue!

Answer (score 1):

To explain this a little

> I need to convert the int(), float(), datetime.datetime objects to
>   str() so I can get length, whereas I do not need to do this with the
>   str() and str() with ascii.

In Python there are a number of built in sequence types, including strings, unicode strings, lists, tuples etc. You can pass any of these types to `len()` and a integer will be returned, as there is a [protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html) in C Python at least which expects these objects to support this behaviour.

```
>>> len("hello")
5
>>> len(["foo", "bar"]
2
```

Many other objects can also be passed to `len()`, including built-ins types like `dictionaries` and custom objects which implement a `__len__()` magic method.

```
>>> len({"foo":"bar"}
1
```

Some objects which are not sequences / containers do not support this however, such as `integer` and `float` types like you mentioned. If you try and pass such objects to `len()`, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

```
>>> len(5)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Same goes for `datetime` objects as you've found out

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> len(datetime.today())
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.datetime' has no len()
```

And this makes sense - `len()` should indicate the number of items in an object. What would you expect a `datetime` object to return?

So you can convert the `datetime` object into a string and count it's characters, but that doesn't really tell you much.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
'2014-04-12 00:36:03.829979'
>>> len(str(datetime.today()))
26
```

Ultimately you shouldn't be trying to call `len()` on a `datetime` object at all - so you should rethink what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: WHat I am doing is writing a lot of data to an excel spreadsheet...including the date data. I need to know the length of any value that's not larger than 60 characters so i can borrow that length value and pass it into the width of each column to determine if I need to text wrap, so it is imparitive that I get the length of the characters of each value, regardless of type. Make sense?

Comment: Based on that explanation, I think my 'even simpler' answer might be your best bet - get the string representation of whatever the thing is (even if it's already a string!), and then use the langth of that string. Don't bother trying to work out if you 'should' string convert it, JFDI!

Comment: I see your thought process - but if you want to only put the date into the excel column (as in YYYY-MM-DD or whatever date format you need), then you can format the datetime object using strftime() and you will always be able to predict its length. It will never be larger than 60 characters so you don't need to call len(). Tom recommends the right way of using isinstance to find the type BTW

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
import datetime
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("Strategic_Land_Resource_Planning_Area"):
    if isinstance(row.APPROVAL_DATE), datetime.datetime):
         print "Yes"
    else:
         print "No"
```

Does that print "Yes"?

Comment: I jsut ran it again. Yes it does.

Comment: My guess is that there's some difference then between your test program and the main one? Possibly print some extra diagnostic info out in the main program and see if it matches the test case? E.g. print stuff like row.APPROVAL_DATE.__class__, repr(row.APPROVAL_DATE) and str(row.APPROVAL_DATE)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I am doing a bit of that as we speak. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's cheaper than donating to charity and more interesting!